# Trying to add some code within useEffect in my react component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ruby-on-rails-7

I am learning react and trying to use `useEffect`. But I am getting this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

To address #1 I checked the react and react-dom versions, they're the same `18.2.0`.
To address #2 I don't think I am (code coming soon). I'm not sure how to check for #3, I don't think there is but then again not sure. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `Greetings to aaaa`;
}, []);

class CustomerOnboarding extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerOnboarding;
```

Above code throws `Invalid hook call` error. However when I put the `useEffect` within the component class I get a slightly different error:

[image]

[image]

I don't know if this is related, but I am using react with ruby on rails. I have other components working just fine, without hooks that is. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use hooks outside components, or in class components at all.

Comment: please check first how to hooks works  !  **Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component** as it says you should not use it inside a class component or outside components

Comment: @monim ok hook should be within the function, get that. Where should the function be defined? In the class or outside of the class?

Comment: class components are not usually recommended. they are an older react paradigm. nowadays most code uses functional components and hooks. check out the new react docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) used for functional componet. for class component you need to use
[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and componentDidMount

In your case :

```
import React  from "react";


class CustomerOnboarding extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() { // this is for class component
    document.title = `Greetings to aaaa`;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerOnboarding;
```

for using of useEffect you can change your Component to functional component :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";


function CustomerOnboarding() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.title = `Greetings to aaaa`;
  },[]);
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default CustomerOnboarding;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can convert your component to function like below

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const CustomerOnboarding = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Greetings to aaaa`;
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default CustomerOnboarding;
```